# How to capture cell content in a Silverlight datagrid?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I would like to capture the value of a cell in a datagrid when the user click on that cell. I dont want to edit the cell, just click on it and capture the value so i can do somthing with it in the viewmodel.  Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your DataGrid is

```
<Controls:DataGrid Name="versionInfo" PreparingCellForEdit="grid_ForEdit" >
```

the handler is

```
private void grid_ForEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox box = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
    // box.Text contains the text in that cell
}
```